# fragment navigation drawer items not displaying

Tags: android

I'm working with material design and for some reason my navigation drawer is not displaying the drawer items.  I think it may have something to do with the below:

[image]

My gradle looks normal as well.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0"
}
```

Comment: RecyclerView is not displayed. Upgrade your android studio,this issue is fixed in the latest version.

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.1

Comment: On Mac, latest is 1.3.1

Comment: update is available in canary channel only . you can use as it is ,only preview of the recyclerview is not available. but it will work when you run it.

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView needs a LayoutManager, have you added this?

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
```

If it still does not work, try an invalidate cache and restart in android studio. If it still does not work you have to download and install the recent version of android studio and it will work.

Comment: Yes, i do have a  LayoutManager added.

Comment: Then try rest of the options. And android studio has version 1.4 released for Mac. Check out their website. This was a bug in the preview and was fixed later.